# What is the term for a game where crossing the stage fills out the area unoccupied by units?

Tags: terminology, genre-identification

What is the name of this 2d game (genre) where the unit controlled by the player (here a blue circle) tries to cross the stage without getting hit by the enemies (here in red) and if it succeeds, any area without units (here the left side) becomes solid?

[image: game schema]

The goal of the game is to fill out the biggest area possible without getting hit.

I remember seeing several clones of this game a long time ago, but can't get the right search keywords to find any of them.

Comment: This isn't a game-identification question, but rather a terminology one.  I've edited the tags as so.

Comment: Isn't that just a [Qix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qix) clone?

Comment: @Nolonar Feel free to post it as an answer